# SharePoint 2010 how did you get the "Welcome" text before the name?

Tags: 2010, editing-menu

SharePoint 2010 how did you get the "Welcome" text before the name?   I just want to put the word "Welcome" after the username displayed the sign in of SharePoint.

So it should say Welcome User.

I created my own welcome.ascx from the original welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript/JQuery code to insert the "Welcome" text before the name.

Using JQuery code you insert the "Welcome" text in the **SearchTopLine** class.

Example:

```
 $(".SearchTopLine span a").prepend("Welcome ");
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, and it was a simple implementation.

Comment: I'm happy to hear it:)